# Trouble understanding piece of code in Python lists

Tags: python, list

I'm having trouble understanding line 7 and line 8. Can anybody explain what these lines do?

```
row1 = ["⬜️","️⬜️","️⬜️"]
row2 = ["⬜️","⬜️","️⬜️"]
row3 = ["⬜️️","⬜️️","⬜️️"]
map = [row1, row2, row3]
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
position = input("Where do you want to put the treasure? ")
horizontal = int(position[0])
vertical = int(position[1])
map[vertical - 1][horizontal - 1] = "X"
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
```

Comment: what exactly you have problem to understand - access char in str by index, conversion to int?

Comment: No, that conversion part is okay, but i'm bit confused between the index of number

Comment: Like why the vertical position is at index 1?

Comment: input will return str. e.g. expected input is `'13'`, so `position[0]` will be `'1'` and `position[1]` will be `'3'`

Comment: Yeah i did asked, tbh i' new with python so i feel like understanding whole logic of code, hope u understand and help me with it ,if possible

Comment: You should find a follow a tutorial. SO is not intended to explain someone's code

Answer (score 2):

`position` receives a string from `input` on line 6. This input is then transformed into row/column coordinates on the following two lines.

On line 7, the first character of `position` is cast to an integer, indicating the row that the treasure is put in, and placed into `horizontal`.

On line 8, the first character of `position` is cast to an integer, indicating the column that the treasure is put in, and placed into `vertical`.

A sample run of the program might look like the following (note that the row/column values are subtracted by 1 on the line following the type conversions, as the coordinates from the input are 1-indexed and Python lists are 0-indexed):

```py
['⬜️', '️⬜️', '️⬜️']
['⬜️', '⬜️', '️⬜️']
['⬜️️', '⬜️️', '⬜️️']
Where do you want to put the treasure? 22
['⬜️', '️⬜️', '️⬜️']
['⬜️', 'X', '️⬜️']
['⬜️️', '⬜️️', '⬜️️']
```

Comment: Can u tell me this, that why (vertical = int(position[1])) the index in vertical case is 1?

Comment: Because the vertical index is given by the second character in the `position` string.

Comment: Let's say I have to print 23 , here 2 is vertical position and 3 is horizontal position, so in this case also the index of vertical element gonna be 1? I'm trying to understand but can u explain a bit in more simple words?

Comment: `position` holds "23". That means `position[0] == 2` and `position[1] == 3`. You're conflating the index of a character in the `position` string with the contents at that index.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything is clear now. That was a big help